# Why is "file" considered a keyword in C#?

Tags: c#, file, keyword, visual-studio-2022

The following code generates `CS9056` ("Types and aliases cannot be named 'file'"):

```cs
public sealed class file
{

}
```

This happens after I upgraded VS to 2022 Preview, 17.4.0. The code used to compile just fine previously. I cannot find any information indicating that `file` was now a keyword in C#. The solution I'm trying to translate builds using the 5.0SDK but targets .NET Framework 4.8.

I do know that types should use uppercase names normally and that I could work around the issue by changing `class file` to `class @file`, but this is in an auto-generated file where I cannot change the generator. And applying some `sed` hacks seems like, well, a hack.

Why is `file` considered a keyword here and what would it be intended for? Can I disable it?

Comment: There's no warning on my machine. Do you have special settings? BTW: Class names begin with an uppercase letter.

Comment: There's no .NET Framework 5.0 SDK - unless you mean the .NET *Core* 5 SDK, which is already out of support. Did you create a .NET *7* project perhaps? That's still .NET *Core* 7 and still in development

Comment: This is a preview-only change (C# 11) to support [file-local types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/6011), documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/breaking-changes/compiler%20breaking%20changes%20-%20dotnet%207#types-cannot-be-named-file). The solution, if you're not willing to change the type name (which you arguably really should, and a generator that doesn't add `@` to *every* identifier just to stay on the safe side is buggy to begin with) is to stick with C# 10 for now.

Comment: Here a repro: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxBAzmAPgAQEwEYCwAUJgMwAEOZAwmQN5FmMXmYAsZAsgBQCUdDTAL5FhhIqTIoAphAA2UgCYVsZAGZR5ReoSZkRQA

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem in .NET (Core) 6, much less .NET Framework projects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Technically it's not .NET Core 5 either, it's just .NET 5. Core was dropped after .NET Core 3, apart from EF Core and ASP.NET MVC Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use .NET 5.0 SDK for building, I also tried .NET 6.0 SDK, but no change.

Comment: @DavidG I know that, and that marketing name change was pretty ... unimpressive. It causes problems like the one in this question all the time, with people confusing .NET Framework and .NET Core all the time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, but it doesn't help if we propagate the naming problems.

Comment: [This breaking change is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/breaking-changes/compiler%20breaking%20changes%20-%20dotnet%207#types-cannot-be-named-file)

Comment: @DavidG: We don't propagate it, on the contrary: We deliberately ignore Microsoft's decision, so that we can minimize the confusion caused by it.

Comment: @Heinzi Which is deeply unhelpful in the long term

Comment: @DavidG: Unhelpful for Microsoft's marketing department: Sure. Unhelpful for the StackOverflow community: That remains to be seen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a change introduced in the compiler in VS 2022 17.4. `file` is apparently now a modifier for type declarations.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/breaking-changes/compiler%20breaking%20changes%20-%20dotnet%207

> Introduced in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4. Starting in C# 11, types cannot be named file. The compiler will report an error on all such type names. To work around this, the type name and all usages must be escaped with an @:

```
class file {} // Error CS9056
class @file {} // No error...
```

> This was done as file is now a modifier for type declarations.
> You can learn more about this change in the associated csharplang issue.

Additional link referenced from docs: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/6011

Comment: Hmmm... Guess I need to find a way to tell XSD.exe (which is the generator that creates this code for me) to work around this. But that's old, too...

Comment: @PMF `xsd.exe` won't generate a .NET 7 project. It will only generate C# files. You'll have to create a .NET 7 project yourself for this problem to occur

Comment: @PMG do you really want to work with xsd in .NET 7?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do have the problem with an existing project, so I don't need to create a new one...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's ugly, I know. But the project is still targeting .NET Framework 4.8. I'll probably replace it when I update it to .NET 6 or 7 (which is on my to-do list)

Comment: @PMF: If you can reproduce this problem with a project that has a `<LangVersion>` explicitly set to `10` or lower, I'd file a bug, as preview or not, it shouldn't be applying C# 11 rules in that case, irrespective of the targeted framework. If `<LangVersion>` isn't specified or is set to `preview`, then there's your issue. Alternatively, of course, just don't use the *preview* version of VS for production code -- there's a reason it's in preview.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In fact I did have `<LangVersion>` set to `latest`, but changing it to 10 does not change anything.

Comment: @PMF: Well, that's probably a bug then, as VS should still be able to build for older versions. The one thing you could check is whether the build succeeds even though the IDE complains (this can happen, especially in preview versions, because the interactive compiler isn't the same version as the version used for building). That said, I'm not 100% sure on the support in preview versions: supporting earlier versions of C# in a preview IDE may not be something MS cares much about, since after all you explicitly chose to use the preview version.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't have much choice there, actually. I need to work with projects that already target .NET 7.0 and others still .NET 5.0 and 6.0. Unfortunately, it's not possible to install VS2022 "official" and "preview" side-by-side.

Comment: And yes, the errors are different. the IDE complains with CS9056, but when building I get CS1031 "type expected" instead. Building from the command line appears to work.

Comment: @PMF: ...yes it is, I'm working with a system like that right now. :P What you cannot do is have one part of your solution build with one VS and part with another, of course (at least not interactively), but that's not a huge limitation. Ultimately, if you want your code to compile for .NET 7 and C# 11, you will have to actually address the breaking issue. Stick with the old (no matter how inconvenient) or bite the bullet and change things to move forward, them's the breaks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247993/discussion-between-pmf-and-jeroen-mostert).

Comment: I worked around the issue by using a different xsd->cs converter. This one changes all entity names to correct pascal casing.